# Is anyone doing visual debugging with Jint?

Tags: c#, javascript, debugging, server-side, jint

I've been using [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) to run server-side JavaScript code and I'm liking it a lot so far.  The one issue I'm having is debugging.

JInt exposes events that can fire when a statement is executed or a breakpoint is hit.  [As mentioned on the Web site](http://jint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging), it would be possible to create a visual debugger that works through this mechanism.

Before I go reinventing the wheel, has anybody done this yet?  Are there any frameworks, libraries, or tools that might facilitate the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually something Sébastien (the coordinator) and I (a developper who helps him) are thinking about : having a debugger working within Visual Studio. However, we have not put a premium on this. Maybe you should try asking directly on the discussion board on codeplex.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your recommendation: http://jint.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=77409